# Diagnose failure in Dell d630

Tags: laptop, dell-latitude, diagnostic

A Dell d630 is showing signs of failure:

- On startup, often nothing is seen on screen. it's about 50:50 if it starts up fine or does nothing
- Plugging in an external monitor when nothing appeared, we did see something on the 2nd monitor, and were able to login
- We have seen rare graphical glitches like odd patterns, entire screen starts flickering - these normally lock the PC up and require a restart

To me this smells like the GPU being bust, does that sound likely or something else? I thing a simple bad connection to the screen wouldn't cause lock-ups?

It's using the nVidia GPU option, not the integrated Intel version. Is it possible to fix/replace the GPU or will it be integrated onto the mainboard?

Comment: Could you add details of the system to your question, it would be good to know if you have an Nvidia graphics chip or you are using an onboard Intel chipset for example...

Comment: Long shot, re-seat your memory modules.

Comment: Seems to be a bog-standard D630 with the nVidia GPU option